# Unit testing in flask with a global setup

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have a simple flask app that I've got deployed in Elastic Beanstalk and I'm trying to write some unit tests for it and having some difficulty.

The app, when it starts, needs to talk to EC2's parameter store ( via ssm ), to download a secret key, which is decrypted via kms.  If you aren't familiar with elasticbeanstalk - when the the flask app is deployed, it's done via httpd/wsgi.

The 'secret' parameter only ever needs to retrieved once - I don't want to go out to ssm for every request to flask.

The problem is that I had something like this:

```
import flask
application = flask.Flask(__name__)

secret = get_ssm_parameter()
application.config['SECRET'] = secret

@application.route('/some/route')
def do_something():
    # does something
```

When I try and test this application, as soon as I do the 'import myapp' into the unit test, it obviously tries to run get_ssm_parameter, which I don't want, but I'm unsure how to create some global setup functions without calling them as soon as I do an import.  So I need some way to import myapp, so that I can then mock out the get_secret before it's called.

The best I've been able to come up with is something like:

```
def get_secret()
    if application.config['SECRET'] is None:
        application.config['SECRET'] = get_ssm_parameter()
    return application.config['SECRET']

@application.route('/some/route')
def route_that_needs_secret():
    secret = get_secret()
    # do some stuff
```

Where upon I retrieve the secret once it's needed in a route, and I set it into the application.config, which keeps it around globally.

Is there a pattern for initializing expensive setup once in a Flask app and keeping those results around between requests?  I wanted to try and stay away from storing the secret in a cache anywhere, but I'm not sure how to keep it around between requests otherwise.

Comment: You could guard that behind `if __name__ == '__main__':`, so it only runs when the file is executed not when it's imported for testing.

Comment: Guarding it via main wouldn't work - it's imported both via WSGI and via the unittest.  It's not running as a stand-alone flask app.